# static initializer: test ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java

I'm studying the `ExceptionInInitializerError` for my certificate exam.
It's clear that only unchecked (runtime) exceptions can be thrown from the static initializer block (no checked), but it doesn't explain to me why the following occurs:

```
public class Test {

    static{
        //throw new NumberFormatException();        //Doesn't compile 
        //int num = Integer.parseInt("sd", 16);     //Compiles 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

When I throw a `new NumberFormatException`, the compiler doesn't allow it.
Why doesn't it throw an `ExceptionInInitializerError` instead?
When the same exception is thrown during runtime, the error is displayed as promised.
I went looking through other articles, but couldn't find an answer. 
It's an important question to understand for the exam though, it appeared in some mock question.

Compilation error:

> Initializer does not complete normally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Java Language Specs:

> It is a compile-time error if a static initializer cannot complete normally (§14.21).
>   <sub>[Chapter 8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7), page 258</sub>

And further:

> A break, continue, return, or throw statement cannot complete normally.
>   <sub>[Chapter 14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21), page 462</sub>

Comment: Thanks for reference. Accept in 5 mins. Very professional btw.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know what error you're seeing, but in Eclipse I get the following:

> Initializer does not complete normally

That perfectly explains why it won't compile. Creating a static block that will unconditionally fail makes no sense, and the compiler is calling you on it.

Solution: Make the exception conditional, i.e. move it inside an `if` statement.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Java. Didn't have a good notion that to "complete normally" was an actual description in JLS. Thanks for the explanation, it's clear.